# Regular expression is not matching new lines

Tags: regex, unobtrusive-validation

I have the following reg ex:

```
"^((?!([\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*@((([\-\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})))).)*$"
```

But it's not matching new lines as well:

https://regex101.com/r/nT6wK0/1

Any ideas how to make it match when there is a new line?

Comment: Suggest using http://regexper.com to see your regex mapped out. [Example](http://regexper.com/#%5E((%3F!(%5B%5Cw!%23%24%25%26'*%2B%5C-%2F%3D%3F%5C%5E_%60%7B%7C%7D~%5D%2B(%5C.%5B%5Cw!%23%24%25%26'*%2B%5C-%2F%3D%3F%5C%5E_%60%7B%7C%7D~%5D%2B)*%40(((%5B%5C-%5Cw%5D%2B%5C.)%2B%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B2%2C4%7D)%7C((%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.)%7B3%7D%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C3%7D)))).)*%24)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I'm curious...

Comment: I want jquery validate to check if an email address is contained within a description field

Comment: @Jimmyt1988: but the provided example does not contain an email adress and matches. Perhaps you should ommit the `^` and `$`. These are anchors, by dropping these, you search for "a pattern in the entire string", regardless of its position. By using word boundaries (`\b`), you can even ensure that it starts/end either at the beginning or with a spacing char between the match and the "environment".

Comment: Ah, you mean negative lookahead, so all fragments that do **not** contain an email address.

Comment: An example of the text being matched would be useful

Comment: You can do the same thing more efficiently with this: `^(?s)(?:(?![a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]).)*$`

Comment: @sln: I get an error on the provided regex, regardless of the engine on regex101...

Comment: And, without anchors, you let valid email addresses be matched.

Comment: @CommuSoft - I'm running it on Perl, not some fly-by-night pseudo regex site.

Comment: Well the comments suggest it should be a js-flavored regex. Shouldn't the kleene star bind with the dot `.` and the dot replaced by `[\S\s]`. Otherwise you should/can only write one character after the address.

Comment: I don't see any JS tags, and the point I was making is the OP is not going to get what he thinks out of this because of the nature of email regexes. You can't just put a negative email address to match inline text, it won't work unless the email regex is the _exact_ defacto regex.

Comment: I guess there are the uninformed who hope though.

Comment: This is for my C# application, there are things called data annotations that come out into jquery validation on the view. The answer i have ticked now checks perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` at the and actually means

> All but a line break character. [(source)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

By replacing it with `[\S\s]`, it means

> All spacing characters and all non-spacing characters; so all characters.

Then it seems to work. You could have used other variants like `[\W\w]`, `[\D\d]`,...

So the "correct" regex (please don't take my word for it, first test this) is:

```
^((?!([\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+(\.[\w!#$%&'*+\-/=?\^_`{|}~]+)*@((([\-\w]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}))))[\S\s])*$
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/cQ9uF3/1).

Comment: Yes yes and more yes! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you only want to match the first line, you can add the multiline option (/m) to include the newline.

If you want the second line to be included you'll need to read ahead an extra line.  How you do that depends on the regex engine: N in sed; getline in awk; -n in perl; ...